# Edge won't display pdf over https

Tags: pdf, https, certificate, microsoft-edge

I have an old web application with apache webserver fronting weblogic server. The user authenticates using a client certificate and a password and can then access pdf files via jsp pages and **https**. When re-testing the application in current browsers I found that the pdf:s won't display in Edge.

I have tried to strip out unrelated code. Note that the user has logged on using an SSL certificate before arriving at `edge_bug.jsp`:

```
<%@ page %>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html"/>
        <title>edge_bug.jsp</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="window.open('testpdf.pdf', 'PDFWin' + new Date().getTime(), 'scrollbars=yes,status=yes,width=370,height=550,resizable=yes')">Open in new window</a>
        <a href="testpdf.pdf" >Open in the same window</a>
   </body>
</html>
```

The links work fine in IE and FireFox, and the pdf is displayed, but in Edge a blank gray window is shown.

If I embed the page in a frameset (old stuff, but the application is old!) then the link that opens the pdf in the same window starts working. The link that opens a new window fails the same way as before. `edge_bug_frameset.jsp`:

```
<%@ page %>
<!DOCtype html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Frameset//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-frameset.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>
        <title>Frames</title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1"/>
    </head>

    <frameset frameborder="0" framespacing="0" border="0">
        <frame marginwidth="0" marginheight="0" src="edge_bug.jsp" name="heading" noresize scrolling="no"/>
        <noframes>Your browser doesn't handle frames.</noframes>
    </frameset>
</html>
```

**Browser version:**

Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0

Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299

**Update:**

I have noticed that the behaviour differs depending on the trust level of the server certificate in the web server.

If the web server has an untrusted certificate (red shield and the text "Certificate error" next to the address bar) the pdf won't show and the behaviour is as described above.

If the web server certificate has the lower trust level (grey padlock next to the address bar) the pdf won't show initially, but if I first choose to always allow pop-up windows, wait 10 seconds and then hit F5 (reload) the pdf is displayed. On subsequent attempts the pdf still won't show initially, but it is displayed after I hit F5 and I no longer need to wait 10 seconds before doing it.

If the web server certificate has the higher trust level (green padlock next to the address bar) the pdf won't show initially but once I choose to always allow pop-up windows it always works.

It should be noted that even though the pdfs are opened in new windows these new windows are NOT pop-up windows; a new window is opened when the user actively clicks on a link.

Comment: If you open the PDF by itself does it work?

Comment: @gregwhitworth I can open the pdf by itself or in Edge via a `file://` url. And through the app if it is embedded in a `frameset`.

Comment: Ok, so I tried to repro this by creating a PDF from this post and I was able to open the PDF using both links. The ONLY difference in the code is I don't have the `<%@ page %>` Here's a screenshot -https://imgur.com/a/5lwNX 

What version of EdgeHTML (… > Settings)  are you using?

Comment: Also, does the `<%@ page >` output anything? I'm assuming no, but just to be clear can you ensure there are no empty spaces or other Unicode chars being placed before the DOCTYPE.

Comment: @gregwhitworth The html has 2 newlines before the `DOCTYPE`, no other chars. I think the problem might only manifest when using certificates and https.

Comment: @gregwhitworth Version is Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299, Microsoft Edge 41.16299.15.0.

Answer (score 1):

To me, this seems like a bug in <strike>Microsoft Edge</strike> Edge HTML.

We have solved it by means of a workaround. We advise our users to avoid Microsoft Edge for our web application.

For some users Microsoft Edge is the default browser. We have advised their IT department to use Enterprise Mode Site Lists to force the use of Internet Explorer for our web application, until Microsoft Edge is running on Chromium.

Answer (score 0):

I came across this post while facing a similar issue where PDFs wouldn't display (ONLY) in Edge. This problem only excisted in production, not when running the code locally. Eventually we figured out our problem had something to do with the configuration of the apache server where the application was running.

It turned out the PDFs were send by the server to the browser in chunks. You can see this in the reponse headers you get with the pdf file: Transfer-Encoding: chunked. Additionally no content-length header was send. So our hypothesis is that probably edge keeps waiting for more chunks to arrive because it doesn't know what length to expect. Therefore it will keep waiting forever, because no more chunks are comming. Apparently other browsers have found a way to deal with this, but Edge can't.

The solution for us was to remove mod_deflate for the pdf files in the apache server. By removing this they are no longer send in chunks and the content-length header was added to the response. I hope this might help someone who is facing similar issues.

Answer (score 0):

I think the latest version of edge 80.x and above might resolve this